# Setting up a webpage on google cloud with https

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have bought a domain name on Google Domains, installed Wordpress Multisite on a Google Cloud VM with Compute Engine, setup a load balancer with 2 instances and an Active Google Managed certificate.

I have followed the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple and pointed the Google DNS at the Load Balancer. I currenty get:

The website working in http (not secure) with the direct IP of the VM.
The balancer switching between the two IPs if I enter the https address (ie returning Page served from: lb-backend-pubdeals-x06k) but not returning the wordpress site.

Address is https://pub.deals

But what I want is someone to type in http://pub.deals and https://pub.deals and get the secure site.

Does anyone have instructions on how to redirect users who arrive at http://pub.deals are then redirected to https://pub.deals?

Thanks Jay

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect users who arrive at `http://pub.deals` are then redirected to `https://pub.deals`? If not, edit your question to make it clear on what you are asking.

Comment: WordPress has that ability. Here is an example tutorial: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/ The Apache web server also has that ability. https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/

Comment: Thank you, now I've rephrased the question my search has returned this, which I'll try   https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect

Comment: Oh wow, you're really quick, do you ever sleep? Thanks, I'll try your suggestion first and let you know!

Comment: I work in the evenings and I just happened to be on Stackoverflow researching my own problem with GCP storage.

Comment: Well thank you, I've seen your name come up a lot, you're a credit to this community

Answer (score 1):

So John Hanley was right, I was over complicating things. For the last 20 years or so I've used hosting companies for my sites, and taken care of ssl when I needed to within wp-config and .htaccess, but this is my first time using google cloud and vm builds, so I followed their docs to apply a google managed ssl. They say in order to issue a google managed sll you need to have a load balancer set up, so I rtfm and set one up. It worked as far as the user was delivered to a secure site of either one of two instances, but I couldn't figure out how to attach them to my vm instance with wordpress on it and hence get my content displayed. I did get the http --> https forward using these docs (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) but I still didn't manage to connect the whole affair to the VM with wordpress on it.

TLDR; I deleted the load balancers and google certificate and did it through wordpress.